# How to falsify claim that 2 samples are from different individuals?

Tags: dna-sequencing, hematology, sequence-analysis, forensics

Given 2 sealed, air-tight vials<sup>1</sup> containing approximately 200 grams each of dried mammal blood.  Task is to prove they are (or are not) from the same individual.

What steps would you take?

Note:

- Vials have been stored in the dark and at a relatively constant temperature between 16C and 23C.
- Vials have been stored for many decades.
- Money is no object.
- You have 1 year's time.
- If there is more information you want regarding the samples, please comment with your question.

---

Edits to respond to questions:

1. My sincere apologies; I was unaware one needed to show their prior work before asking a question.  I've read numerous articles on forensic DNA profiling, human genome sequencing, and several
   companies' websites who provide DNA sequencing services.  Yes, clearly it's easier to prove a difference.  Forensic DNA profiling frequently uses a tiny fraction of genome, such as measuring restriction fragment length polymorphism (RFLP) or short tandem repeats (STR).  RFLP appears to be about 95% reliable.  My goal is closer to 99.999% reliable.
2. For my purposes, I'd like the proof to be extremely good, much better than the 95% reliability of RFLP.  Indeed, identical twins would be a problem in general. In my specific case identical births won't be a factor.
3. Thank you for mentioning spurious results in whole genome sequencing. It's something I hadn't read anything about. Agreed, blood type first, etc.  But imagine:  all simple tests like blood type match perfectly.  Now we're down to DNA and anything else (I admit ignorance) that might differentiate.  As above, forensic RFLP DNA fingerprinting is only 95% reliable; not good enough for the imaginary billion dollar bet I'm making on the results, if that helps?

---

Possible answer:  As a non-biologist, I imagine being able to extract complete<sup>2</sup> DNA from both samples, fully sequencing it<sup>3</sup>, and then comparing<sup>4</sup> the results of the sequencing.  Is this even close to correct?

---

Footnotes:

1. The blood samples were taken, dried and sealed with proper caution to avoid contamination and ensure long-term storage.
2. I have no idea how this might be done, but it appears that DNA can be extracted from some kinds of dried blood from what I've read.
3. Sequencing DNA appears to be nearly a commodity lab product these days from Google searching.  Correct or no?
4. I assume there is some viable way to compare the completed sequences' data once obtained, but have only found articles mentioning techniques for doing so with small segments of the larger full sequence.

---

Resources I've read:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_profiling
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsatellite
- https://www.findlaw.com/criminal/criminal-procedure/how-dna-evidence-works.html
- https://sequencing.com/
- https://med.stanford.edu/news/all-news/2022/01/dna-sequencing-technique.html
- https://www.genome.gov/genetics-glossary/DNA-Fingerprinting
- https://www.nature.com/scitable/topicpage/forensics-dna-fingerprinting-and-codis-736/

Comment: Your question got a few downvotes, likely because you haven't presented any prior research (which is expected on this site). As a start, you can read [DNA profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_profiling). Note that full-genome sequencing is very expensive and labourous, and most of the times unnecessary. Also note that it is significantly easier to prove that the samples belong to two different individuals (you just have to find an observable genetic difference), while it is more difficult to reliably show the samples belong to the same individual.

Comment: What are the standards of "proof" that you're looking for? (Identical twins could scupper your plans, as in many murder mysteries)

Comment: Whole genome sequencing is likely overkill, and also has potential to generate spurious results, depending on how it's analyzed. You might want to spend a little time googling forensic DNA testing methodologies, including their statistical probabilities of generating a false match (or mismatch) under different scenarios. You could also take a progressive testing approach, starting with some simple tests to eliminate any obvious clues. Do they belong to the same blood type group? If so, what's the next test you would perform?